# How to add the extra row(s) present in Excel Dataframe2 back into Dataframe1 and vice-versa?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, openpyxl

I have an Excel file, which contains two sheets i.e. **old sheet** and **new sheet**. The task is to generate difference between two sheets and print difference in third sheet.

**Old Sheet**
[image: Old Sheet]

**New Sheet**
[image: New Sheet]

**Note-** Each row contains 1 file data and data is *Dictionary type*

I am comparing the sheets with this code

```
writer2= pd.ExcelWriter(fvc, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') #taking value of fvc from GUI
olddf= pd.read_excel(fvc, sheet_name=0,na_filter=False)
newdf= pd.read_excel(fvc, sheet_name=1,na_filter=False)

comparison_values = olddf.values == newdf.values
rows,cols=np.where(comparison_values==False)
for item in zip(rows,cols):
    olddf.iloc[item[0], item[1]] = '{} --> {}'.format(olddf.iloc[item[0], item[1]],newdf.iloc[item[0], item[1]])    

olddf.to_excel(writer2,sheet_name='Delta Sheet',index=False,header=True)
writer2.save()
```

Now this is working the way I wanted to when the two dataframes have same number of rows, but if one dataframe has extra rows it is not printing and shows **ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)**.

So is it possible that if somehow in a **dataframe** if it has some **extra rows** then **append** those rows in other **dataframe** so that it can make both the **dataframe** equal and comparison is possible.

Like in **old sheet** there are 15 rows of data and in **new sheet** 17 rows, so that means in new sheet some new file has been added and that's why it can't be compared. So can I print that row in the Final Output.
I've tried merging, isin, difference etc. different solutions from **Stackoverflow** but nothing seems to working for me.

**If needed more clarification about question please do ask.**

Thanks for your Help **:)**

Comment: You should probably narrow your criteria for comparison and add some kind of index.

Comment: @CharlieClark Can you explain what? I didn't quite get you